# Android: How can I use the new Chromecast icons with CastCompanionLibrary

Tags: android, chromecast

I've seen new ChromeCast icons around:

[image: New Chromecast Icons]

And I'd really like to use them in my app, as the old icon is completely transparent in the action bar when casting is enabled (the on-state icon is the same color as my action bar).

I'm under the impression that these icons come from the MediaRouter library, and I have a feeling it hasn't been updated with these new icons yet..

Is there a way I can override the icons in the CastCompanionLibrary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was referencing an out-dated version of MediaRouter in my build.gradle;

```
compile 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:19.0.1'
```

instead of

```
compile 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:+'
```