# How to get new android cast icons

Tags: android

I am trying to use Chromecast icon in my app. My problem is am still seeing the older version of cast image (without white filling on connected). How can I update it newer version with filling?

I followed the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23828737/android-how-can-i-use-the-new-chromecast-icons-with-castcompanionlibrary), and updated the settings in gradle build as but its not working

```
dependencies {  
    compile "com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:19.0.1"  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the answer confused you. You *should* use:

```
compile 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:20.+'
```

Comment: not pinning the version can also be kind of dangerous ( new version coming out -> breaking everything or just introducing small subile bugs .. ) - not a recommendation I would make
Mainly applies to this version of your answer http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/25290495/1